# testing extensions without buildkit

Tags: extension, testing

We have a civicrm instance which we installed from the download page on civicrm.org, not via buildkit. We also have a bunch of custom extensions specific for our use case. Until now these extensions were untested. We now want to make unit tests for these extensions. Unfortunatly all test documentation is about sites installed using buildkit. Is there a way to start testing our extensions without changing the way we install and update our civicrm?

Comment: Buildkit sites do some nice stuff to help with testing, they have a range of tools available like `civix` which can generate tests, `phpunit4` which seems to be the recommended version, and they create a test database for CiviCRM. If you know what buildkit does then you should be able to do the same for a non-buildkit site.